# Get Image size(int bytes) before decoding android

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I've an image (3648x2736) around 4.19 MB(size in disk) and I wanted to load it in my application but it crashed as it should because of not enough memory. So to avoid these kind of crashes I put a validator before decoding the images(No, I do not want to use `inSampleSize` to make it smaller).

```
    long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    long nativeUsage = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();
    long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    long heapRemaining = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    long memoryLeft = maxMemory - (heapSize - heapRemaining) - nativeUsage;


    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    int bitmapSize = options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 4;

    if (bitmapSize < memoryLeft)
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
```

Now one thing I want to make sure is, am I calculating `bitmapSize` properly ? Because the image file size is only 4.19 MB and `memoryLeft` was more than 8 MB, yet app crashed. That means it's storing every pixel as 4 bytes(PNGs), right ? then shouldn't it be 3 bytes for jpeg ? or is there something else I need to know ?

Comment: What's the actual values of `bitmapSize` and `memoryLeft` at runtime? As you've said 4.19MB is just the size of image in disk. After decoding, even if you just use 1 byte per pixel it's 3648 * 2736 = 9980928 which is well over 9MB already.

Comment: `memoryLeft` was around 8 MB and `bitmapSize` was around 35 MB

Answer (score 1):

Since Bitmap is just a set of uncompressed pixels no matters what format it is - png or jpeg or else. Only factor you should remember is `Bitmap.Config` which describe color scheme for bitmap. For example `Config.RGB_565` will take 2 bytes per pixel (5 bit red, 6 bit green, 5 bit green channel) and `Config.ARGB_8888` will take 4 bytes per pixel (8 bits per each channel).
You can set Bitmap.Config while decoding image using `BitmapFactory.Options.inPreferredConfig` but as I understood from [BitmapFactory.Options docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig) this is not guaranteed.